# Thermodynamics of cloud formation

Tags: thermodynamics, atmospheric-science

I have been thinking about cloud formation for a while and wanted to know if I have the right idea.

Clouds are formed by water vapor rising higher and higher into the atmosphere and reaching a certain point of saturation (low temp, but that also means it has a lower saturation pressure). At some point, the water vapor condenses and becomes saturated liquid - but due to thermal variations in the atmosphere, is also evaporating at the same time. What we see as the fluffy things in the sky is essentially a vapor-liquid equilibrium.

The reason some clouds are larger than others is simply because some parcels of air are simply larger than others.

One thing I can't seem to explain to myself is why they look fluffy and why some clouds are darker than others... Something related to dust particles and contamination?

Please feel free to point flaws in my logic as well. I'd be happy to know. Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend moving this post to "https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/?tags=meteorology". A search of "https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmeteorology%5Dclouds" for "clouds" had 229 hits. There are entire books devoted to water vapor and it's thermodynamic effects. Water is a magical molecule.

Comment: I think the clouds (or my favorite word that meteorologists classify them as a kind of: hydrometeors) are ice, collected at small objects on which they gather to form crystals. When they are heavy enough they fall and melt along the way. There are lifeforms that depend on being spread by rain, which help cause rain.

Comment: See Microphysics of Clouds and Precipitation by Pruppacher and Klett.